# "Undeliverable" email address, but only for first time emailing someone?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

**Short version**:

I am unable to email **new** contacts associated with a specific organization  when manually entering their email address. I receive an `Undeliverable` email from Microsoft whenever emailing someone for the *first* time (within organization). Double clicking someone's contact link from the staff directory associated with the org allows me to email them successfully, but manually typing in their email address returns `Undeliverable`.

**Note**: I am typing out email address exactly as it appears in directory, and I have verified there are no spelling errors or special characters.

**Long version:**

I am attempting to email a user within a specific organization -- their email address is usually in the format `firstname.lastname@myorganization.org`. Sometimes it deviates to something like `firstname.lastname2@myorganization.org`

When using the staff directory associated with `myorganization.org`, I can use the link for someone's email address to open a new email window and **successfully** email them.

If I copy and paste the email address (exactly as it appears) from the directory, any email I try to send returns `Undeliverable`. Hovering over the email address I typed also displays no information.

If I successfully email someone for the **first** time (using contact link), then I manually enter their email address into a **new** email, then my second email is successfully sent.

So, my email is failing to send **first email** to a new contact when **manually entering** their email address. If I email them once, then manually enter email, there are no issues.

**Note:** I only experience this issue using Microsoft app installed on my computer. When emailing someone from web browser version of Exchange, I do not receive any errors (even if I am manually typing the email address vs. fetching from staff directory. Consequently, I believe the issue has something to do with my computer and/or app, rather than the Exchange platform itself.

Is this a Microsoft bug? Am I doing something wrong here? I just want to manually type in email addresses for new contacts who I wish to email, without having to go through the staff directory to find their contact link and email them.

Comment: “I only experience this issue using Microsoft app installed on my computer.” - What application are you referring to exactly?

Comment: The Microsoft exchange desktop app. @Ramhound

Comment: What is Exchange desktop app? Outlook?

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood the relationship between Outlook and Exchange. It is the Outlook windows desktop app — I just have a Microsoft exchange account that I use to log in.

Comment: Does this only occurs on Outlook client? Can you reproduce this issue on the web mail?

Comment: This is only on the Outlook client. When using web mail, I can manually enter a user's email address (without using the directory) and send them a first email with no problem.

Comment: Not sure what is interrupting with this. You may install available updates for Office first to see if it helps.  If you are using Office 365, try SARA tool: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4098558/how-to-scan-outlook-by-using-the-sara-tool

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that out.